# how return distance dbgeography in meter?

Tags: c#, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-5, spatial, geographic-distance

in this example i need to limit search for seraching just places in arround of 10000 meters for example , this method is dosen't work for me .
this is my code :

```
  using (GeolocationTestEntities context = new GeolocationTestEntities ())
        {


            var distance = 10000;
            var distanceInMeters = distance * 0.6214;

            var CurrentLocation = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(" + CurrentLat + " " + CurrentLng + ")");
                var places = (from u in context.schoolinfo
                              where u.Location.Distance(CurrentLocation) < distanceInMeters
                              select u).Take(10).Select(x => new schoollinfo() { Name = x.name, Lat = x.Location.Latitude, Lng = x.Location.Longitude, Distance = x.Location.Distance(CurrentLocation) });
                var nearschools = places.ToList();
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Cookie");
                cookie["CurrentLat"] = CurrentLat;
                cookie["CurrentLng"] = CurrentLng;
                this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                return Json(nearschools, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

thanks,

Comment: Try different co-ordinates. What records are in DBGeography? Are there lat / long within the current location? Without this info we can only guess...  Also you actually forgot to ask a question. Did it work before? What guide are you following?

Comment: hi, i records a list of a lat/long , my question it s how can i search just places in a round of 10 Km for example , start position it's current location

Comment: Please [edit] your question with additional information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use (distance * 0.6214). Because Distance() metod is already use meter.